# How to aggregate across a $substr in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection, ***ledger***, with the following document format:

```
  {
    _id: ###,
    month: 202112,
    name: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    gross_revenue: 482.28
  }
```

The month actually contains both the year and month, YYYYMM. And there are multiple entries per 'month'. What I'm wanting to do is sum the gross_revenue values across the years. So take a $substr of month to get the year and then sum up gross_revenue.The result would ideally look like this:

```
2019: 99999.99,
2020: 88888.88,
.
.
```

I can aggregate for a given month, and I can get the substr, but can't figure out how to do combine them to aggregate by year.

```
db.ledger.aggregate([ { $match: {month: 202111} },{ $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$gross_revenue" } } } ] )

db.ledger.aggregate([{$project: { year: {$substr:["$month", 0,4]}}}])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- group by year (we can use any aggregation operator to group)
- replace root to make the expected output

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70638109-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":{"$substrCP":["$month", 0, 4]},
   "sum":{"$sum":"$gross_revenue"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot":
  {"newRoot":{"$arrayToObject":[[{"k":"$_id", "v":"$sum"}]]}}}])
```

Comment: The `k-v/replaceRoot` trick achieves the OP goal but yields data as keys, e.g. `{'2021':1082.28}`.  I think the solution is better off without it to yield `{_id: '2021', sum: 1082.28}`.  It also makes it much easier to adapt/add new aggs for each month later e.g. `{_id:'2021', sum:1082.28, avg: 975.10}`.  Avoid mixing data and formatting.

Comment: yes data on keys is bad idea, but its like the last stage that goes to the client, so doesn't cause problems